# Set multiple values to `self` object via loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm overwriting some user DB data from a concern when a different data comes in (fetching that from a remote server). Here's a pseudo code:

```
def update_user_data
  new_data = fetch_new_data // this returns a Hash, e.g. {foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'}

  self.foo = new_data[:foo]
  self.bar = new_data[:bar]
end
```

I'm trying to make this more intelligent with some kind of a loop. So that I don't end up with 30+ similar lines of code.

I get an `undefined method 'att=' for #<User:>` error and I understand why that happens, I just can't find the solution.

```
USER_ATTRIBUTES = [:foo, :bar]

USER_ATTRIBUTES.each do |att|
  self.att = adapt_data[att]
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is an ActiveRecord model, you should do this:

```
USER_ATTRIBUTES.each do |attr|
  write_attribute(attr, adapt_data[attr])
end
```

Comment: For some reason I get `ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute 'foo'`. Something to do with the array values being symbols?

Comment: Well, is there column `foo` on that model?

Comment: There is. I think the problem comes because it's an alias attribute. Other fields that are stored in the DB with the same name work just fine, but not when it's an alias as this one. This is in the model: `alias_attribute attr, :"encr_#{attr}"` where `attr` would be `foo`

Comment: @abpetkov: ah yes, this must be it.

Comment: I'm still accepting since this is another problem and your solution works.